# Azure AD Attributes query does not yield existing data

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, active-directory

We are using Azure Active Directory in an hybrid mode with our on premise AD.

I am trying to get "manager" and "companyName" attributes from Azure AD Accounts, those accounts do not exists on Active Directory on premise.

The attributes I am trying to get are empty, but they are shown on the "Microsoft Entra ID" GUI.

I  am using PowerShell(Get-AzADUser) with the module AZ, I also tried GraphAPI directly, no results.

Is the issue, that those attributes should come from AD on premise synchronization ?
Is there a way around this ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, you won't get these **attributes** in PowerShell response if that user **does not** have those properties values updated on the "Microsoft Entra ID" GUI.

I have one Azure AD user named **`Sridevi`** with both **companyName** and **Manager** properties as below:

[image]

Initially, I connected to Microsoft Graph with **`User.Read.All`** permission by running below PowerShell command:

```
 Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I used below script to get **companyName** and **Manager** **properties** of user via PowerShell:

```
$user = Get-MgUser -UserId "userId" -ExpandProperty "Manager" -Property "displayName, companyName, manager"

$manager = $user.manager
$managerName = $null

if ($manager -ne $null) {
    $managerDetails = Get-MgUser -UserId $manager.id -Property "displayName"
    $managerName = $managerDetails.displayName
}

$user | Select-Object displayName, companyName, @{Name="ManagerName"; Expression={$managerName}}
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can make use of below **modified** script to get the same properties of all Azure AD users:

```
$allUsers = Get-MgUser -All -ExpandProperty "Manager" -Property "displayName, companyName, manager"

foreach ($user in $allUsers) {
    $manager = $user.manager
    $managerName = $null

    if ($manager -ne $null -and $manager.id -ne $null) {
        $managerDetails = Get-MgUser -UserId $manager.id -Property "displayName"
        $managerName = $managerDetails.displayName
    }

    $user | Select-Object displayName, companyName, @{Name="ManagerName"; Expression={$managerName}}
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: using MGUser with the expandProperty option did the trick